# In R, how do you compute multiple mean scores based on partial variable names in a single function / loop?

Tags: r, psych, likert

Hi everyone hope you're well.

I was wondering if anyone has any idea how to create a set of mean scores based on the first few characters in a set of variables. The field is psychology and I am trying to score a personality trait instrument using concise code with no repetition, but I am coming short.

An example data frame and naming convention is below:

```
df <- tibble(
  psyAnger_01 = rnorm(10),
  psyAnger_02 = rnorm(10),
  psyAnger_03 = rnorm(10),
  psyAnger_04 = rnorm(10),
  narAnger_01 = rnorm(10),
  narAnger_02 = rnorm(10),
  narAnger_03 = rnorm(10),
  narAnger_04 = rnorm(10),
  psyArrog_01 = rnorm(10),
  psyArrog_02 = rnorm(10),
  psyArrog_03 = rnorm(10),
  psyArrog_04 = rnorm(10),
  )
```

In the real data frame I have dozens of variables (and multiple data frames) so I am trying to calculate means based on a partial string of the column name i.e., `psyAnger`. I can do this with a `pmap()` as below:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(psyAnger = pmap_dbl(
  select(., starts_with("psyAnger")),
  ~ mean(c(...))))
```

This works perfectly and produces a variable `psyAnger` with a mean of the other 4. Unfortunately I am now struggling to extend this out to the full data frame without copy and pasting and changing the variable names. For example:

```
df <- df %>% mutate(narAnger = pmap_dbl(
  select(., starts_with("narAnger")),
  ~ mean(c(...))))
```

I had the idea of trying to feed in a vector of scale names into the loop e.g., something like the below:

`columns <- c("psyAnger", "narAnger", "psyArrog")`

but I've got no clue idea how to integrate the two functions. Desired output would be all the variables having mean scores for each participant as the last columns in the dataset. This is my first time creating an MRE so please let me know if anything needs amending.'

Comment: There are many ways of selecting columns to summarise based on (partial) matches of their names.  In your example, would replacing `starts_with("psyAnger")` with `contains("Anger")` give you what you want?  The relevant tidyverse.org page is [here](https://tidyselect.r-lib.org/reference/starts_with.html).

Comment: In fact, since you're calculating summaries rather then performing mutations, why not just `df %>% summarise(across(contains("Anger"), mean))`?

Comment: A final thought.  Your data frame is not [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html) because your column *names* contain information relevant to your analysis  (`Anger` vs `Arrog`ance, `nar` vs `psy` and maybe even the numeric suffix).  Make it tidy and your life will be simpler (and your code more concise) in the long run.

Comment: Thanks for getting back so quickly. Apologies if I wasn't clear, what I'm trying to do is `psyAnger` as a new variable that is a mean of the 4 columns that are prefixed `psyAnger_x` i.e., `psyAnger_01, psyAnger_02` etc., which that `pmap()` function does do. Rather than listing out the 4 existing variables I have named them so I can `starts_with("psyAnger")` or contains("psyAnger"). The challenge is that I have many different versions of `psyAnger` that represent different psychological constructs, am trying to find a way of automating that mean score creation based on the partial names.

Comment: Ah!  Then my comment about (un)tidyness is even more relevant.  Give me a moment...

Answer (score 0):

I maintain a package on github which helps with this kind of problems. We can use `dplyover::over` and extract the name stems with `cut_names()`. Then use `across()` to get all variables that start with each stem and calculate the `rowMeans`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(dplyover) # https://github.com/TimTeaFan/dplyover

# when generating random data please set a seed for reproducability
set.seed(123)

# data
df <- tibble(
  psyAnger_01 = rnorm(10),
  psyAnger_02 = rnorm(10),
  psyAnger_03 = rnorm(10),
  psyAnger_04 = rnorm(10),
  narAnger_01 = rnorm(10),
  narAnger_02 = rnorm(10),
  narAnger_03 = rnorm(10),
  narAnger_04 = rnorm(10),
  psyArrog_01 = rnorm(10),
  psyArrog_02 = rnorm(10),
  psyArrog_03 = rnorm(10),
  psyArrog_04 = rnorm(10),
)

df %>% 
  transmute(over(cut_names("_\\d+"),
              ~ rowMeans(across(starts_with(.x)))))

#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    psyAnger narAnger psyArrog
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1  0.00556   -0.138 -0.0716 
#>  2 -0.0959    -0.762  0.450  
#>  3  0.457     -0.159 -0.499  
#>  4  0.0826     0.452 -0.0967 
#>  5 -0.0575    -0.194  0.177  
#>  6  0.626      0.431 -0.00309
#>  7  0.588     -0.447  0.651  
#>  8 -0.785     -0.262 -0.0852 
#>  9 -0.357      0.502 -0.448  
#> 10 -0.0113     0.511  0.00431
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

We can use a workaround to create a similar approach with `purrr::map`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

var_nms <- gsub("_\\d+", "", names(df)) %>% unique()

df %>% 
  transmute(map_dfc(set_names(var_nms),
                     ~ rowMeans(across(starts_with(.x)))))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    psyAnger narAnger psyArrog
#>       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#>  1  0.00556   -0.138 -0.0716 
#>  2 -0.0959    -0.762  0.450  
#>  3  0.457     -0.159 -0.499  
#>  4  0.0826     0.452 -0.0967 
#>  5 -0.0575    -0.194  0.177  
#>  6  0.626      0.431 -0.00309
#>  7  0.588     -0.447  0.651  
#>  8 -0.785     -0.262 -0.0852 
#>  9 -0.357      0.502 -0.448  
#> 10 -0.0113     0.511  0.00431
```

<sup>Created on 2022-08-11 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

OK.  As I mentioned in one of my comments, your life will be much simpler if you invest a little time in making your data [tidy](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/vignettes/tidy-data.html).  Here this means extracting information from the column names and putting it into the data frame.

Here's a quick and dirty way of doing that:

```
library(tidyverse)

dfLong <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    everything(),
    names_to=c("Prefix", "Emotion", "Test"),
    names_sep=c(3, 8),
    values_to="Score"
  )
# A tibble: 120 × 4
   Prefix Emotion Test     Score
   <chr>  <chr>   <chr>    <dbl>
 1 psy    Anger   _01   -0.560  
 2 psy    Anger   _02    1.22   
 3 psy    Anger   _03   -1.07   
 4 psy    Anger   _04    0.426  
 5 nar    Anger   _01   -0.695  
 6 nar    Anger   _02    0.253  
 7 nar    Anger   _03    0.380  
 8 nar    Anger   _04   -0.491  
 9 psy    Arrog   _01    0.00576
10 psy    Arrog   _02    0.994  
# … with 110 more rows
```

There are very sophisticated options for defining how to pivot the data.  You can use regular expressions in `names_pattern`, supply a separator character in `names_sep` and so on.  Here, I've specified a vector of character positions.  One obvious thing that could be tidied up is the leading underscore in `Test`.  If I've misinterpreted the meaning of some aspects of the data, you can just rename the columns of `dfLong` to something more appropriate.

Now that's done, getting your summaries is straightforward.

```
dfLong %>% 
  group_by(Prefix, Emotion) %>% 
  summarise(
    N=n(),
    Mean=mean(Score),
    .groups="drop"
  )
# A tibble: 3 × 4
  Prefix Emotion     N     Mean
  <chr>  <chr>   <int>    <dbl>
1 nar    Anger      40 -0.00672
2 psy    Anger      40  0.0452 
3 psy    Arrog      40  0.00786
```

This code is *robust* in the sense that it will work without alteration regardless of the number of tests, the names of the emotions being tested and the different prefixes being used, it will work without alteration.

It occurs to me that you said you want "a new variable that is a mean of the 4 columns", as if you have repeated measurements on a series of ten subjects.  That's also easy.  We just have to introduce a new variable denoting the subject before converting to long format.

```
df %>% 
  mutate(Subject=row_number()) %>% 
  pivot_longer(
    -Subject,
    names_to=c("Prefix", "Emotion", "Test"),
    names_sep=c(3, 8),
    values_to="Score"
  ) %>% 
  group_by(Subject, Prefix, Emotion) %>% 
  summarise(
    N=n(),
    Mean=mean(Score),
    .groups="drop"
  )
# A tibble: 30 × 5
   Subject Prefix Emotion     N     Mean
     <int> <chr>  <chr>   <int>    <dbl>
 1       1 nar    Anger       4 -0.138  
 2       1 psy    Anger       4  0.00556
 3       1 psy    Arrog       4 -0.0716 
 4       2 nar    Anger       4 -0.762  
 5       2 psy    Anger       4 -0.0959 
 6       2 psy    Arrog       4  0.450  
 7       3 nar    Anger       4 -0.159  
 8       3 psy    Anger       4  0.457  
 9       3 psy    Arrog       4 -0.499  
10       4 nar    Anger       4  0.452  
# … with 20 more rows
```

My comments about robustness apply equally to this variation, with the addition that it's also robust with respect to the number of subjects.

For reproducibility, I created the test `df` with the following code:

```
# For reprducibility
set.seed(123)

df <- tibble(
  psyAnger_01 = rnorm(10),
  psyAnger_02 = rnorm(10),
  psyAnger_03 = rnorm(10),
  psyAnger_04 = rnorm(10),
  narAnger_01 = rnorm(10),
  narAnger_02 = rnorm(10),
  narAnger_03 = rnorm(10),
  narAnger_04 = rnorm(10),
  psyArrog_01 = rnorm(10),
  psyArrog_02 = rnorm(10),
  psyArrog_03 = rnorm(10),
  psyArrog_04 = rnorm(10),
)
```

Comment: This is brilliant thank you, ended up going with this approach. Thank you for taking the time @Limey hugely appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome.  if the So community has solved your problem, please accept one of the answers.  That will indicate to future users that this question has been answered and potentially help them find answers to their questions.